# Distinguish between plain objects and class types

Tags: typescript

How can I distinguish a plain object type from a class type?

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public a: number) {}
}

declare let obj: {a: number}
declare let inst: Foo

// Either one would be fine.
type IsPlainObject<T> = ???
type IsClassType<T> = ???
```

This is required if you want to use "mapped types" on plain objects, but never on class types.

**edit:** Class types seem to be identical to interfaces in many (most? all?) cases:

```
class Foo { a?: number }
class Bar { a?: number }

type A = Foo extends Bar ? 1 : 0  // => 1
type B = Bar extends Foo ? 1 : 0  // => 1

type Obj = { a?: number }

type C = Foo extends Obj ? 1 : 0  // => 1
type D = Obj extends Foo ? 1 : 0  // => 1
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20AssertEqual%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20(%3CG%3E()%20%3D%3E%20G%20extends%20T%20%3F%201%20%3A%200)%20extends%20(%3CG%3E()%20%3D%3E%20G%20extends%20U%20%3F%201%20%3A%200)%20%3F%20true%20%3A%20false%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%20a%3F%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%20a%3F%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20Foo%20extends%20Bar%20%3F%201%20%3A%200%20%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%201%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%3F%201%20%3A%200%20%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%201%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Obj%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3F%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20C%20%3D%20Foo%20extends%20Obj%20%3F%201%20%3A%200%20%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%201%0D%0Atype%20D%20%3D%20Obj%20extends%20Foo%20%3F%201%20%3A%200%20%20%2F%2F%20%3D%3E%201%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20T1%20%3D%20AssertEqual%3CFoo%2C%20Bar%3E%0D%0Atype%20T2%20%3D%20AssertEqual%3CBar%2C%20Foo%3E%0D%0Atype%20T3%20%3D%20AssertEqual%3CFoo%2C%20Obj%3E%0D%0Atype%20T4%20%3D%20AssertEqual%3CObj%2C%20Foo%3E)

### Relevant issues

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29063
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5303#issuecomment-148894708

Comment: I think you would have to look at the prototype, maybe not possible in the type system. The only difference of a class is that something other than the base `Object` is in the prototype chain, right?

Comment: @H.B. Yeah exactly. I'm already doing this at runtime, but if I don't do it at the type level too, class types are mangled by a mapped type.

Comment: What about https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cb9wb7

Comment: @WilliamLohan The problem is _not_ runtime type-checking. Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: Well its not strictly runtime checking, see the mouse over of `param` on line 14, but understandable if not what you are looking for

Comment: @WilliamLohan Right, but it requires a runtime feature (`instanceof`).

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29063

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me:

```
type PlainObject<T> = T extends Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]> ? T : never;
```